# Cannot read property of objects retrieved via node-mongodb-native

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**EDIT:** I have figured this out, the error came from the browser requesting 'favicon.ico', just had to check that a document is returned

```
if (doc) res.send(doc.title);
```

I am connecting to a MongoHQ database and retrieving a single document from my collection "CMS".

```
mongodb.connect(mongourl, function(err, db){
    db.collection('CMS', function(err, collection) {
        app.get('/:slug', function(req, res){
            collection.findOne({slug:req.params.slug}, function(err, doc){
                res.send(doc.title);
            })
        });
    });
});
```

The above code shows the title in the browser, but then crashed node, giving this error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
    at /Users/tom/git/cms/app.js:24:17
    at /Users/tom/git/cms/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:962:5
    at /Users/tom/git/cms/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:131:9
    at /Users/tom/git/cms/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:173:11
    at /Users/tom/git/cms/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:454:35
    at Cursor.close (/Users/tom/git/cms/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:662:5)
    at Cursor.nextObject (/Users/tom/git/cms/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:454:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/tom/git/cms/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:442:12)
    at [object Object].g (events.js:156:14)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:88:20)
```

I don't undrstand why it would show the title, but then crash with an error saying the title property doesn't exist? Any suggestions?

Comment: You are probably getting an error. Try printing `err` along with `doc.title`. You aren't checker `err` anywhere in fact, so any of your callbacks might be failing.